# Turning display off while playing video file in VLC player

Tags: windows-8, vlc-media-player, power-management

Is there any option native to VLC player on windows to automatically turn off the display when playing a video in it? Could be handy when I want to listen only to audio with the screen off for battery efficiency.
I am using Windows 8 on Dell laptop.

Answer (score 1):

The video could be turned off by disabling video and enabling screensaver in the video settings (in show all setting) of vlc player.

Answer (score 0):

If you use cvlc or nvlc, you can use the `--no-video` option:

```
nvlc --no-video "http://youtube.com/cool_music_video"
```